# How to programmatically setup a CallBacks for a UIButton?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Manually built:

```
[btnRun addTarget:self action:@selector(RunApp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
```

---

Programmatically built: something of the following like ??

```
- (void) setRunButton:(UIButton*)objectName mySelector:(NSString*)funcName myControlEvent:(NSString*) controlEvent
{
    [objectName addTarget:self action:@selector(funcName) forControlEvents:controlEvent];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'd need something like the following:

```
- (void)setRunButton:(UIButton *)objectName mySelector:(NSString *)action myControlEvent:(UIControlEvents)controlEvent {

   [objectName addTarget:self action:NSSelectorFromString(action) forControlEvents:controlEvent];

}
```

It is unusual to pass a selector as an `NSString` but you can use `NSSelectorFromString()` to convert the string name of the selector into a selector.

Control events parameters are not strings they are an enumeration so I have changed the `myControlEvent` parameter to have the `UIControlEvents` type.

It would be more usual to pass the selector to the method using `@selector(action)`.  However, `@selector` is handled at compile time so the parameter isn't actually an `NSString`.  In this case the method would look like:

```
- (void)setRunButton:(UIButton *)objectName mySelector:(SEL)action myControlEvent:(UIControlEvents)controlEvent {

   [objectName addTarget:self action:action forControlEvents:controlEvent];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the entire selector as a parameter

```
- (void) setRunButton:(UIButton*)objectName mySelector:(SEL)action myControlEvent:(NSString*) controlEvent
{
    [objectName addTarget:self action:action forControlEvents:controlEvent];
}
```